# Why is arrow.now() not in a range containing today's day?

Tags: python, python-3.x, arrow-python, python-arrow

I am testing the ability, in `arrow`, to check whether a date is in a range of dates:

```
>>> arrow.get('06/09/2017', 'DD/MM/YYYY') in arrow.Arrow.range('day', arrow.get('06/09/2017', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), arrow.get('06/07/2018', 'DD/MM/YYYY'))
True

>>> arrow.get('06/09/2017', 'DD/MM/YYYY') in arrow.Arrow.range('day', arrow.get('07/09/2017', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), arrow.get('06/07/2018', 'DD/MM/YYYY'))
False
```

So far so good. I then tried to use `.now()` in the same construction (today is 6 Sept 2017, the date in the tests above):

```
>>> arrow.now()
<Arrow [2017-09-06T21:09:02.402790+02:00]>

>>> arrow.now() in arrow.Arrow.range('day', arrow.get('06/09/2017', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), arrow.get('06/07/2018', 'DD/MM/YYYY'))
False
```

**Why is the result `False` despite `.now()` being in the range?**

```
>>> arrow.Arrow.range('day', arrow.get('06/09/2017', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), arrow.get('06/07/2018', 'DD/MM/YYYY'))
[<Arrow [2017-09-06T00:00:00+00:00]>, <Arrow [2017-09-07T00:00:00+00:00]>, ...
```

Comment: You've constructed your range by day, so it's not technically  going to include the return of `arrow.now()` unless you just happen to call it exactly at midnight. Options include: change the way the range is constructed, floor/ceiling the query date, or do something with a time delta.

Comment: @excaza: ok I understand, thanks. It will look for the exact literal date (at midnight) and `.now()` has the right day/mon/year but not the time. Would you mind turning your comment into an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: I would recommend using epoch time to check the date range. @excaza is totally correct, was about to write the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way your range is currently constructed is by using a `'day'` as your range's `frame` parameter so, unless your query manages to land exactly at midnight, checking for it the range is going to return `False`.

Within Arrow itself, the simplest option is probably to use [`floor()`](http://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#arrow.arrow.Arrow.floor) or [`ceiling()`](http://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#arrow.arrow.Arrow.ceiling) to normalize your query to how the range is constructed:

```
>> myrange = arrow.Arrow.range('day', arrow.get('06/09/2017', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), arrow.get('06/07/2018', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), tz='local')
>> arrow.now().floor('day') in myrange
True
```

Note that I've changed the `tz` parameter to `'local'` so the comparison to `arrow.now()` is correct. I personally try to do everything with UTC or epoch time rather than keeping track of timezones.

Alternatively, you can do a simple logical check to see if the current time is after than your range's minimum and before your range's maximum:

```
>> myrange = arrow.Arrow.range('day', arrow.get('06/09/2017', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), arrow.get('06/07/2018', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), tz='local')
>> myrange[0] <= arrow.now() <= myrange[-1]
True
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you what you want:

```
>>> arrow.utcnow().floor('day') in arrow.Arrow.range('day', arrow.get('05/09/2017', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), arrow.get('06/07/2018', 'DD/MM/YYYY'))
True
```

The key is in the *floor()* method of the Arrow class: this limits your Arrow object and is required because (as @excaza mentioned) the range gives you day objects at midnight.

I used the *utcnow()* method instead of the *now()* method because your *arrow.get()* usage creates utc dates.